# python search word after match dash

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

ihi, I want to search for a following word after a match, so when if i search in a string `"i use a table blue"` with (\w+) with that regex i solver the problem, but `"i use a table blue-green-red"` so how can i get the entire word without using the (\w+).(\w+).(\w+) n number of times. how can i get that, but there is always a carriage return after the `"i use a table blue-green-red\n"`  or  `"i use a table blue\n"` so how can i get the following entire word  even if there are n number of dash in the following word

Comment: It's hard to understand from your description where's the problem. Can you edit your question and add some sample input and expected output?

Comment: hi, i want to search for a following word after a match

Comment: hi, i want to search for a following word after a match, so when if i search in a string "i use a table blue" with (\w+) with that regex i solver the problem, but "i use a table blue-green-red" so how can i get the entire word without using the (\w+).(\w+).(\w+) n number of times. how can i get that, but there is always a carriage return after the "i use a table blue-green-red\n"  or  "i use a table blue\n" so how can i get the following entire word  even if there are n number of dash in the following word

Comment: hi i edit the question for you to help me

Comment: So you want to match string `"i use a table blue"` inside the text `"i use a table blue-green-red\n"`?

Comment: This still isn’t clear. You aren’t actually explaining what you’re trying to do, nor your current solution. Once you’ve rewritten your question into something which is easy to read and understand, it might be good to include some (properly formatted) examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to extract is the *last word* (or *trailing word*) in the matched search, even if it has dashes. You also indicate that you are guaranteed a newline `\n` at the end of the phrase.

With that in mind, a possible solution would be to include a greedy operator right after the word \w, and curb it with a newline, something like:

```
regex = r"i use a table (\w+.*)\n"
```

which matches both:

```
"i use a table blue\n"
```

and

```
"i use a table blue-green-red\n"
```

extracting the last word.

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/34MBP3/1

Comment: RegEx101 is always a helpful recommendation, such a practical tool!

Comment: thanks a lot mate you understand what i tryed in the last part, thnks a lot mate, and for the link for regular expression, yep it was correct there is always a carriage return at the end of the line, but may or may not come with 1, 2 or 3 dashes, thanks a lot for your time, i give  the correct answer

Comment: Happy to help!!